# Validate an array of objects in Postman

Tags: arrays, validation, postman

I am quite new with Postman and not a particularly good programmer. I am testing an API and trying to validate a part of a response that has an array in it looking like this:

```
"processors": [
        {
            "name": "ARTPEC-5",
            "type": "SOC",
            "url": null,
            "releaseNotes": null,
            "cdnUrl": null,
            "cdnReleaseNotes": null
        },
        {
            "name": "SSL",
            "type": "SOC",
            "url": null,
            "releaseNotes": null,
            "cdnUrl": null,
            "cdnReleaseNotes": null
        },
        {
            "name": "ARTPEC-7",
            "type": "SOC",
            "url": null,
            "releaseNotes": null,
            "cdnUrl": null,
            "cdnReleaseNotes": null
        }
    ]
```

Now, I would like to validate that the array comes with the above objects. They may come in any order in the array, so I cannot refer to the objects using index like jsonData.processors[0] and then validate them one by one like that. I need a general validation method. I have tried this that did not work:

```
pm.test("Check if the response has processors", function () {
     pm.expect(jsonData.processors).to.have.members([
  {
            "name": "ARTPEC-5",
            "type": "SOC",
            "url": null,
            "releaseNotes": null,
            "cdnUrl": null,
            "cdnReleaseNotes": null
        },
        {
            "name": "SSL",
            "type": "SOC",
            "url": null,
            "releaseNotes": null,
            "cdnUrl": null,
            "cdnReleaseNotes": null
        },
        {
            "name": "ARTPEC-7",
            "type": "SOC",
            "url": null,
            "releaseNotes": null,
            "cdnUrl": null,
            "cdnReleaseNotes": null
        }]);
});
```

This approach only gives me the cryptic error message  *AssertionError: expected [ Array(3) ] to have the same members as [ Array(3) ]*

Answer (score 0):

By using [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#differenceWith) you will get empty array if there is no difference in the array objects and their properties. That you can assert as  -

```
var _ = require('lodash')

var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

var arr = _.differenceWith(objects, [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }], _.isEqual);

console.log(arr);
console.log(objects.length);

// assert that difference should be empty

pm.test("array difference", function () {
    pm.expect([]).to.eql(arr)
});
```